# Setting time with PHP

Tags: php

We are creating a website for our canoe club , one of the things we want to be able to do is place race times from previous races ( sprints and marathons ) . We want to place the best and worst times for each age group and the get averages from these times as qualifying times .

What I cannot figure out is how to enter these times into the database as times . They are normally in hours , minutes , seconds and split seconds . How do I use the time function to set these times .

Thank you in advance for any help on this topic .

Comment: Can u share some sample code

Comment: To be honest , right now there is no code for this specific page part of the website . Once I figure out how to set the time I can go ahead and start coding the page .

Comment: Did u get the idea? I hope

Answer (score 1):

Than only this link will help you.

[PHP DATE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

And as per your need you can use this function:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Make sure your database date field follow the MYSQL date format.